# filebeat does not resolve complicated hosts parameter in kafka output connector

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

I'm using the Filebeat -> Kafka output connector and I would like to construct the hosts and topic parameter based on the information traveling in the messages that filebeat is processing at that moment.

To my surprise, specifying exactly the same expression leads to it being resolved for the topic and not for the hosts field. Any advice on how I can achieve my goal?

My configuration is below:

```
kafka.yaml: |
  processors:
  - add_kubernetes_metadata:
      namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  # Drop all log lines that don't contain kubernetes.labels.entry field
  - drop_event:
      when:
          not:
            regexp:
              kubernetes.labels.entry: ".*"
  filebeat.config_dir: /conf/
  output.kafka: 
    hosts: '%{[kubernetes][labels][entry]}'
    topic: '%{[kubernetes][labels][entry]}'
    required_acks: 1
    version: 0.11.0.0
    client_id: filebeat
    bulk_max_size: 100
    max_message_bytes: 20480
```

And here's the error message I'm getting from filebeat:

```
2018/05/09 01:54:29.805431 log.go:36: INFO Failed to connect to broker [[%{[kubernetes][labels][entry]} dial tcp: address %{[kubernetes][labels][entry]}: missing port in address]]: %!s(MISSING)
```

I did try adding port to the above config, the error message then still shows that the field has not been resolved:

```
2018/05/09 02:13:41.392742 log.go:36: INFO client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker [[%{[kubernetes][labels][entry]}:9092]]
2018/05/09 02:13:41.392854 log.go:36: INFO Failed to connect to broker [[%{[kubernetes][labels][entry]}:9092 dial tcp: address %{[kubernetes][labels][entry]}:9092: unexpected '[' in address]]: %!s(MISSING)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-variables-in-output-hosts-doesnt-work/106226) on the Elastic forum:

```
You cannot control hosts or files (in the case of the file output) via variables. Doing so would require Beats to manage state and connections to each different host. You can only use variables to control the destination topic, but not the broker.
```

So it's not possible to achieve what I'd like to do at this time.